# How to record a phone call in swift automatically?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to record all phone calls automatically and save them.
When call UI appear and user pick-up the call, Can it start recording ?

Answer (score 1):

No. It would be a great privacy violation. The only way you can do it is to build your own soft-phone application. Even in that case you must inform user about the call recording fact.